# Meson: print buildtarget filename from executable()

Tags: meson-build

I'd like to print filename from `buildtarget` created by [`executable()`](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#executable). Looking into [`class Executable`](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/blob/master/mesonbuild/build.py#L1631) I tried `ping.name`:

```
ping = executable('ping', [
        'ping.c',
        'ping_common.c',
        'ping6_common.c',
        'node_info.c',
        git_version_h
    ],
    include_directories : inc,
    dependencies : [ 
        cap_dep,
        idn_dep,
        intl_dep,
        m_dep,
        resolv_dep
    ],
    link_with : [libcommon],
    install: true)

message(ping.name))
```

But it gives an error:

```
ping/meson.build:23:17: ERROR: Expecting lparen got rparen.
```

The same is for `ping.filename`, there is no `to_string()`. Are these "private" or anyhow hidden?

`BuildTarget` is [documented](https://mesonbuild.com/Build-targets.html), but there is no method described. Thus generally howto understand which methods are public and which private for certain meson class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better link to reference is [this one](https://mesonbuild.com/Reference-manual.html#build-target-object) since it shows all supported methods. And in your case it also should work `full_path()` method:

```
message(ping.full_path())
```

If you need just target file name and don't have `name()`, then some string/array manipulation should work:

```
message(ping.full_path().split('/')[-1])
```

so, it should split full pathname into array of strings and print the last element of the array.

Answer (score 3):

`name` is actually a method, you missed `(`

```
message(ping.name())
```

Comment: I tested various things, including `ping.filename()`, but not `ping.name()`. In the end I'm going to use plain string because `.name()` is from `0.54.0` and I need support for older distros as well.

Comment: I see now, really missing one char, thus not tested as a function. I also tested it both as attributes `message(ping.name)`.

Comment: Meson's DSL doesn't have any attributes, FYI, they're always methods.